# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById return null on GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am simply trying to get my map fragment to then be able to execute getmapasync and draw markers on it. However my mapFragment value is always null. I dont understand why. I read from other answers that it might something to do with the fact that my fragment is inside a frame and therefore is some sort of child.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TrackerService.class));
        bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TrackerService.class), myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "MAP READY");
        mMap = googleMap;
        drawLocationMarkers();
    }
```

And the XML:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_card"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have u implemented your Activity class with OnMapReadyCallback

Comment: Please refer the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

Comment: @Nainal yes i have, i have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: @Nainal however the code errors beofre, it errors on the line mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); since mapFragment is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change  your layout to use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`

`android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`